# Windows Server 2008 or 2012 on IBM X3850

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, ibm-server

I'm having trouble installing WS2008 or 2012 on IBM x3850. Both should be supported but somehow I cannot install any of them on this server. Please note that I don’t have KMV or something similar, I'm doing this just for a school project and for learning System Center 2012. I downloaded the ServerGuide for both WS2008 and 2012 and everything goes fine until the part where ServerGuide is searching for the OS DVD. It says it cannot find the selected Operating System and I should insert the correct DVD and press OK. Is there anything special I should do when I burn the Windows Server ISO images to DVD or is there any other way to install them on this server?

Just to recap: I start the server, boot from DVD, ServerGuide starts, it creates the RAID, I select an Operating System and it copies the necessary drivers. These steps work very well. The problem is on the next Step called Searching Operating System or something like that, I put the WS2008 or 2012 DVD i've burned before, but no matter what OS I've choosen it never finds it.

Comment: Are you sure your burned copies are good ?

Comment: Yes, I used imgburn to burn the ISO files to DVD. When I try the DVD in another PC it works as expected.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of ServerGuide

Comment: OK, I solved the Problem. I used an USB DVD Reader and it worked.

Comment: For anyone who may be curious: the instructions here: http://www.intowindows.com/install-windows-10-from-usb-drive/ explain how you can install Windows 10 from a USB thumb drive.  I have personally used this technique to install Windows Server 2012 R2 and it works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 other options.

1) Use RUFUS to write the image onto a USB stick, and install from USB-stick
2) Use a USB DVD-Reader, as you have done 
3) Install Fedora/Ubuntu/Debian, and run Windows Server in VirtualBox 
(
    Ubuntu/Debian: 
    Works only with kernel-boot-options "intel_iommu=on iommu=soft" 
)